# Aggregating rows while filtering by them

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a PostgreSQL table called `teams` with the columns `team_id` and `team_name`.

```
+---------+----------------+
| team_id |   team_name    |
+---------+----------------+
|       1 | Avengers       |
|       2 | Justice League |
|       3 | Suicide Squad  |
+---------+----------------+
```

I also have another table, `people`, with the columns `person_id`, `person_name`, and `team_id`.

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| person_id | person_name | team_id |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
|         1 | Linda P     |       1 |
|         2 | John F      |       1 |
|         3 | John R      |       3 |
|         4 | George F    |       2 |
|         5 | Bethe E     |       3 |
|         6 | Melinda R   |       2 |
|         7 | Bill M      |       1 |
|         8 | Linda S     |       2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

Now I want to return a new (joined) table with the columns `team_id`, `team_name`, and `people`, the last one is an aggregated array of (JSONs of) the people on that team. So far so good. Lets say I use lateral join:

```
select 
    teams.*,
    people.*
from teams
join lateral (
    select
        array_agg(row_to_json(people)) people
    from people
    where teams.team_id = people.team_id
) people on true
```

However, I want to be able to:

- Filter out teams if they contain certain people - for example, "I don't want the team George is on", or "I don't want the team Linda is on if it's the same team John is on".
- Hide people from all teams if they meet a condition (while still being able to filter teams by them) - for example, "Hide all the Lindas" will make all the Lindas not show on the people column, but I can still filter out teams with both Lindas and Johns.

In reality, the table of people is actually a big complex joined table, and I want to keep that logic in one place inside the query (this is where I'm having trouble). I also don't want to convert the array of JSONs back to rows.

So for example, I want to filter out teams with Johns, unless they also have a Linda on them, and hide all Lindas. I should receive:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| team_id |   team_name    |                                      people                                       |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | Avengers       | {'{person_id: 2, person_name: John F}, {person_id: 7, person_name: Bill M}'}      |
|       2 | Justice League | {'{person_id: 6, person_name: Melinda R}, {person_id: 4, person_name: George F}'} |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING` to filter out teams. Use `CASE WHEN` to decide which members to display.

```
select *
from
(
  select
    team_id,
    array_agg(case when person_name <> 'Linda' then row_to_json(people) end) as members
  from people
  group by team_id
  having count(*) filter (where person_name = 'George') = 0
     and 
     (
       count(*) filter (where person_name = 'John') = 0
       or
       count(*) filter (where person_name = 'Linda') > 0
     )
) p
join teams t on t.team_id = p.team_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more elegant than my old query but apparently less performative.

Comment: Well, for the condtions there are additional counts necessary that can make this slower than the original query. An index on `people(team_id, person_name)` may help.